# Django SQL Server studio backend doesn't support altering from/to AutoField

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django

Please help me I tried to connect to the database
The connection was successful and the rules were lifted, but I have this problem

```
 raise NotImplementedError("the backend doesn't support altering from/to %s." % t.__name__)
NotImplementedError: the backend doesn't support altering from/to AutoField.




Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying account.0001_initial... OK
  Applying account.0002_email_max_length... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying profiles.0001_initial... OK
  Applying goals.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\athamma\.virtualenvs\src-NXdWuPOU\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\athamma\.virtualenvs\src-NXdWuPOU\li

Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, goals, notifications, profiles, sessions, sites, socialaccont
Running migrations:
  Applying goals.0001_initial... OK
  Applying goals.0002_approvedgoals... OK
  Applying goals.0003_auto_20210928_1206... OK
  Applying goals.0004_goal_cer... OK
  Applying goals.0005_auto_20211027_1918...Traceback (most recent call last):
```

raise NotImplementedError("the backend doesn't support altering from/to %s." % t.**name**)
NotImplementedError: the backend doesn't support altering from/to AutoField.

Comment: last masseg 


raise NotImplementedError("the backend doesn't support altering from/to %s." % t.__name__)
NotImplementedError: the backend doesn't support altering from/to AutoField.

Answer (score 0):

I think it cached, i had this problem and solve it with omit all files in dir:
appName/migrations/

and again run these commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Caution: before run server, drop your DB and create new one, don't overwrite on old DB!